# How do I mark a Python package as Python 2 only?

Tags: python, package

I have a [Python package](https://github.com/flycheck/sphinxcontrib-emacs) that only runs on Python 2. It has the following classifiers in its setup.py:

```
setup(
    # ...
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2 :: Only',
    ])
```

However, if I create a virtualenv with Python 3, pip happily installs this package.

How do I prevent the package being installed? Should my setup.py throw an error based on `sys.version_info`? Can I stop pip even downloading the package?

Comment: The classifiers are *normative*; pip doesn't care about them and doesn't inspect them, let alone enforce.

Comment: Don't you mean informative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In setup.py, add this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] != 2:
    sys.stderr.write("This package only supports Python 2.\n")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that you have to wait until the package is installed to find out it doesn't support Python >= 3. Whereas it would be better to include this information in the metadata (`python_requires` and `classifiers`) so that tools can find this information early before installing the package.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of `setuptools` and `pip`, if you're using `setup.py`, here's how to specify a requirement of Python 2 only (specifically Python 2.7):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="my_package_name",
    python_requires='>=2.7,<3.0',
    # ...
)
```

It would also be good to include classifiers, like this:

```
setup(
    name="my_package_name",
    python_requires='>=2.7,<3.0',
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2 :: Only",
    ],
)
```